# Error is shown when values are inserted in an array

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Here is my html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="form1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate"><br>
    <h3>Questions</h3><button class="new_btn">Add New</button><br>
    <div class="add_ques">
        <span>Question1</span><textarea name="ques1" id="ques1"></textarea><br>
        Option1<select class="option" name="opt1" id="opt1">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select><br>
    </div>
</form>
```

When add new button is clicked another set of Question and Option fields will be appended to the end. Name and id of that fields will be automatically incremented. For example: name of next question will be ques2. I need to get the values of all the question using jquery. I have tried following code:

```
jQuery(".form1").submit(function(){
        for (var i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
            qus[i] = jQuery('#ques'+i).val();
        }
        alert(qus);
});
```

No alert is displayed. And error is shown in the console on line "qus[i] = jQuery('.ques'+i).val();" . Help me to find error in my code

Comment: What's `counter` in `var i = 1; i <= counter; i++`?

Comment: how's you are getting `counter` ?

Comment: i get counter value during the "Add New" button click. Counter value is set to the number of times we click Add New button. And i have checked whether counter value is set and its working correctly.

Comment: I would read up on e.preventdefault. You'll need to it prevent the form from reloading the page. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false/1357151#1357151

Comment: 1,`id` need to be unique per element and i smell that `id="ques1"` is repleated for each element.2. since it's `id` so in jQuery code `jQuery('.ques'+i)` need to be `jQuery('#ques'+i)`. Also show your add more button code . so that we can know that actually `ques1,ques2,ques3...` are generated properly or not?4, `preventDefault()` needed too

Comment: Even after giving e.preventdefault the page get reloaded

Comment: @Sandra  read my previous comment

Comment: @Sandra why don't you try append() to add new input fields in form, it will automatically result in all form fields values passed  when you submit form.

Comment: @Alive to Die--Anant Singh name is generated properly and id's are also unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution

```
jQuery(".form1").submit(function(e){

                    qus =[];

                    for (var i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
                        qus.push(jQuery('#ques'+i).val());

                    }

            });
```